# Approaches to Prove Every Planar Graph $G$ is $6$-colorable

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

I have asked similar question in an earlier post, but this time I would like to get better understanding of the difference between using strong induction and regular induction to prove that every planar Graph $G$ is $6$-colorable.

My understanding: by induction hypothesis, for $n \ge 6$ and assume that every simple, connected and planner graph on up to $n$ vertices is $6$-colorable. Then we can not regular induction here because we have the connectivity condition, but if we removed connectivity condition from the assumption, then we could use regular expression. The issue here is if we delete a vertex $u$ from $G$, which might make the graph disconnected and this is why we need the strong induction and connectivity in the assumption.

Please let me know your thought of my understanding about proving every planar graph $G$ is $6$-colorable and why we need connectivity condition in the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to require connectivity, it just makes your life harder.

There's one reason to try to stick to connected graphs, and that's probably why the source you're reading from does it: Euler's formula. We only have $|V(G)| - |E(G)| + |F(G)| = 2$ for a plane embedding of a *connected* planar graph, and this is the equation from which we derive $|E(G)| \le 3|V(G)| - 6$ (for graphs on at least $3$ vertices), which in turn lets us deduce that there is a vertex of degree less than $6$.

We can avoid this by observing that every planar graph can be turned into a *connected* planar graph by adding edges. Therefore if $|E(G)| \le 3|V(G)| - 6$ holds for all connected planar graphs on at least $3$ vertices, it holds for *all* planar graphs. Having deduced this, we can use this inequality with impunity and no care for whether our graph is connected.

But, if you want to prove the theorem for connected graphs, then we use strong induction, and say:

- If the graph is connected, do the usual thing where you remove a vertex, color the remainder by the induction hypothesis, and put the vertex back.
- If the graph is not connected, color every connected component by the induction hypothesis. (This is the part where we need strong induction: if the original graph has $n$ vertices, then the components can have any number of vertices between $1$ and $n-1$, so we need the induction hypothesis for all of those cases.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please explain more what do you mean by "which in turn lets us deduce that there is a vertex of degree less than 6."?

Comment: I was skipping over that step because I assume that you understand the overall idea of the proof, and just want to know how the induction works. Is that not true?

Comment: Yes, I got you now. Thanks. What is the different compared to regular induction? Can not regular induction handle disconnectivity case if we remove a vertex from the graph?

Comment: The part where we remove a vertex can be handled by regular induction. We need strong induction when we say "color every connected component by the induction hypothesis", since the connected components can be considerably smaller than the original graph.

Comment: Thanks Misha. Last question, the proof I got, he claims, "$G$ is simple, connected. Connected to color each component separately because different components don't interact with each other with respect to coloring." I got that assumption, but why he assumed that we need connectivity to color each component separately when we assumed originally that "$G$ is already connected and has one single component? This part confuses me.

Comment: In the proof by strong induction, even if we *start* with a connected graph $G$, when we remove a vertex $v$, $G-v$ might not be connected.